# Override officeUI nav chevron icon

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

in the office-ui react fabric how do i over ride the chevon icon
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/nav

In the documentation there is this interface

```
INavStyles
```

but i am not able to override it with my own icons. i want to replace the existing chevron with *FolderHorizontal* and *OpenFolderHorizontal* icons instead

```
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Nav, INavProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Nav';

import { initializeIcons } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icons';
initializeIcons(/* optional base url */);

....
....


public _getNavLink(): any[] {
return [
  {
    name: 'Home',
    url: '',
    links: [{
      name: 'Activity',
      url: '',
      key: 'key1'
    },
    {
      name: 'News',
      url: '',
      key: 'key2'
    }],
    isExpanded: true
  }
]}

public render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Nav
         getStyles={() => {
          return {
            chevronIcon: {
              color: 'transparent',
              transform: 'rotate(0)',
              selectors: {
                '&:before': {
                  color: 'rgb(51, 51, 51)',
                  fontFamily: "FabricMDL2Icons-7",
                  content: '"\\F12B"',
                },
                '.is-expanded > * > &:before': {
                  fontFamily: "FabricMDL2Icons-5",
                  content: '"\\ED25"',
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }}
      groups={
        [
          {
            links: this._getNavLink() 
          }
        ]
      }
      expandedStateText={ 'expanded' }
      collapsedStateText={ 'collapsed' }
      selectedKey={ 'key3' }
    />
  </div>
);
```

}

[image]

Comment: 0
down vote

Just a heads up that the styling prop is now called simply 'styles' and accepts a function like in the example, or just an object of styles.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/dashboard/src/components/Nav/Nav.types.ts#L43

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `getStyles` property on the Nav component to apply CSS to the chevronIcon slot:

```
<Nav
    getStyles={ () => { return { 
        chevronIcon: { 
          color: 'transparent',
          transform: 'rotate(0)',
          selectors: {
            '&:before': { 
              color: 'rgb(51, 51, 51)', 
              fontFamily: "FabricMDL2Icons-7",
              content: '"\\F12B"',
            },
            '.is-expanded > * > &:before': { 
              fontFamily: "FabricMDL2Icons-5",
              content: '"\\ED25"',
            }
          }
        }
      }} }
      groups={...}
      expandedStateText={ 'expanded' }
      collapsedStateText={ 'collapsed' }
      selectedKey={ 'key3' }
    />
```

The solution is basically hiding away the original chevron, disables the rotation and shows desired icons in the background.

Note that the icons for `FolderHorizontal` and `OpenFolderHorizontal` are set using their Unicode representation which can be looked up in the Github repo (e.g. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/search?q=FolderHorizontal). The two icons live in seperate font families, hence the fontFamily directive.

**UPDATE [20180417]**

Make sure the fonts are initialized using `initializeIcons();` or using a custom path. The font files should then be loaded and appear in your DevTools:

[image]

Note that - unlike your code - we are using

```
import { initializeIcons } from '@uifabric/icons';
```

to import the `initializeIcons`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. But looks like the Unicode is not getting rendered. I have added an image on my answer, check the first Node.  What am i doing wrong? :(

Comment: Are you sure the fonts are loaded? Note the path to import `initializeIcons` as well. We updated our post accordingly to clear things up.

Comment: Is there any other solution to resolve this feature because method `getStyles` doesn't exists anymore?