# Is there a simple way to change the chevron icons in a nested Nav component?

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react, fluent-ui

I personally and a lot of customers think the default icons for links with nested items in the [Nav](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/nav) component are strange. Hence I want their look and behavior to change from this:

[image: default look and feel]

to this:

[image: intended look and feel]

(In the screenshots the size is also different, but that's just from the context's I took them. I just want to change the icons).
The latter is btw also used by Microsoft OWA (Outlook Online), which also uses Fluent UI React. The only thing that I could come up with (but which doesn't work really well) was to hide the default chevron using styles and modifying the rendered link `onRenderLink` to display the other chevrons.

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49542450/override-officeui-nav-chevron-icon), but changing the icons via style is no option and I guess no longer a preferred way by fluent ui.

Is there any better or official way I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a look at the code and unfortunately the icon is baked into the `Nav` component. Your best option would be to style the icon similar to what is being done [in this codepen](https://codepen.io/khmakoto/pen/YzqyaLb?editors=0010).

Comment: Cool, thanks. This works like a charm. I changed it a bit to my needs (example shortend to relevant part):
`<Nav styles={props => ({ chevronIcon: [transform: props.isExpanded ? 'rotate(0deg)' :'rotate(-90deg)'] })} />`